# Other ways to initialize empty character array in c/cpp

Tags: gcc, clang

char arr[n] = "";
This works fine with gcc but with clang below error is seen :
error: variable-sized object may not be initialized

Is it fine using memset with '\0' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use explicit `memset`:

```
char a[n];
memset(a, 0, n);
```